# Add data from second MySQL table to the result from the first one

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 2 tables:

```
+-----------+
|   users   |
+-----------+
|   John    |
|   Peter   |
|   Alex    |
+-----------+
```

and

```
+-----------+
|   banned  |
+-----------+
|   John    |
|   Peter   |
+-----------+
```

Is it possible to `SELECT * FROM users` and combine the result with the second table in order to find out if the user banned or not?

Comment: Try a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following using a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html):

```
-- with CASE WHEN
SELECT users.*, CASE WHEN banned.username IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isBanned
FROM users LEFT JOIN banned ON users.username = banned.username

-- without CASE WHEN (thanks to @forpas!)
SELECT users.*, banned.username IS NOT NULL AS isBanned
FROM users LEFT JOIN banned ON users.username = banned.username
```

In case the user doesn't match to the `banned` table, the username (and the other columns too) is `NULL`. You can use a `CASE WHEN` to check if the username is `NULL`.

You can also use [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) instead of a `LEFT JOIN` to get this additional information:

```
SELECT *, EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM banned WHERE users.username = banned.username) AS isBanned
FROM users
```

And there is a third option using [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT users.*, IF(banned.username IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isBanned
FROM users LEFT JOIN banned ON users.username = banned.username
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8c6379a8e4b38d1b5acf079c9cb5b52)